# Loop vs Union all

Tags: sql, loops, union

I'm trying to learn some advanced techniques. I have the following
query that executes monthly disenrollment information as of '(Date)'
with `union all`s.

Is there a shorter way of doing this?  Executing this take a long
time.

Thanks!

```
select left((datename(mm, me.StateDisenrollDate)),3) as ReportedMonth,
me.StateDisenrollDate,
me.ReinstatementDate,
me.MemberID,
dis.DRI_Name,
case
    when me.ReinstatementDate is null then 'Disenrolled'
    else 'Reinstated' end as Status
from tblMemEnrollment me
left join tlkpDisenrolReasInvestigated dis on dis.DisenrolReasInvestigID = me.DisenrolRsnInvstgtdID
where me.StateDisenrollDate between '1-1-2015' and '1/31/2015'
and me.ReinstatementDate is null or me.ReinstatementDate between '1/1/2015' and '1/31/2015'
and SubscriberID like '%H%'

union all

select left((datename(mm, me.StateDisenrollDate)),3) as ReportedMonth,
me.StateDisenrollDate,
me.ReinstatementDate,
me.MemberID,
dis.DRI_Name,
case
    when me.ReinstatementDate is null then 'Disenrolled'
    else 'Reinstated' end as Status
from tblMemEnrollment me
left join tlkpDisenrolReasInvestigated dis on dis.DisenrolReasInvestigID = me.DisenrolRsnInvstgtdID
where me.StateDisenrollDate between '2-1-2015' and '2/28/2015'
and me.ReinstatementDate is null or me.ReinstatementDate between '2/1/2015' and '2/28/2015'
and SubscriberID like '%H%'

union all

select left((datename(mm, me.StateDisenrollDate)),3) as ReportedMonth,
me.StateDisenrollDate,
me.ReinstatementDate,
me.MemberID,
dis.DRI_Name,
case
    when me.ReinstatementDate is null then 'Disenrolled'
    else 'Reinstated' end as Status
from tblMemEnrollment me
left join tlkpDisenrolReasInvestigated dis on dis.DisenrolReasInvestigID = me.DisenrolRsnInvstgtdID
where me.StateDisenrollDate between '3-1-2015' and '3/31/2015' 
and me.ReinstatementDate is null or me.ReinstatementDate between '3/1/2015' and '3/31/2015'
and SubscriberID like '%H%'


union all

select left((datename(mm, me.StateDisenrollDate)),3) as ReportedMonth,
me.StateDisenrollDate,
me.ReinstatementDate,
me.MemberID,
dis.DRI_Name,
case
    when me.ReinstatementDate is null then 'Disenrolled'
    else 'Reinstated' end as Status
from tblMemEnrollment me
left join tlkpDisenrolReasInvestigated dis on dis.DisenrolReasInvestigID = me.DisenrolRsnInvstgtdID
where me.StateDisenrollDate between '4/1/2015' and '4/30/2015'
and me.ReinstatementDate is null or me.ReinstatementDate between '4/1/2015' and '4/30/2015'
and SubscriberID like '%H%'


union all

select left((datename(mm, me.StateDisenrollDate)),3) as ReportedMonth,
me.StateDisenrollDate,
me.ReinstatementDate,
me.MemberID,
dis.DRI_Name,
case
    when me.ReinstatementDate is null then 'Disenrolled'
    else 'Reinstated' end as Status
from tblMemEnrollment me
left join tlkpDisenrolReasInvestigated dis on dis.DisenrolReasInvestigID = me.DisenrolRsnInvstgtdID
where me.StateDisenrollDate between '5-1-2015' and getdate()
and me.ReinstatementDate is null or me.ReinstatementDate between '5/1/2015' and getdate()
and SubscriberID like '%H%'
```

Comment: You should edit your question and describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm attempting to yield the same results but using a while loop statement.

Comment: Loops are indeed an "advanced technique", but that doesn't make them better. Loops should pretty much always be a last resort in SQL, where set-based solutions are preferable.

Comment: In general looping will be a lot slower than an appropriate set based solution in SQL. Looks like you're trying to show the same information in each statement, separated into each month of the year so far? Please edit your question to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry buddy but the whole point of SQL is that you be declarative and not imperative (eg. write loops). Consider SQL to be the advanced technique.

Comment: Mantra: "lops and cursors are evil, ommmmmmm"

Comment: Bridge, that's correct.  I'm trying to separated into each month of the year.  But if this technique yields slower execution, I think it'll be better sticking with the union all although the query will be 12 times longer.

Answer (score 1):

You got the same column list and the same joins, just different WHERE-conditions, so simply combine them using `OR`:

```
SELECT LEFT((datename(mm, me.StateDisenrollDate)),3) AS ReportedMonth,
me.StateDisenrollDate,
me.ReinstatementDate,
me.MemberID,
dis.DRI_Name,
CASE
    WHEN me.ReinstatementDate IS NULL THEN 'Disenrolled'
    ELSE 'Reinstated' end AS Status
FROM tblMemEnrollment me
LEFT JOIN tlkpDisenrolReasInvestigated dis ON dis.DisenrolReasInvestigID = me.DisenrolRsnInvstgtdID
WHERE (me.StateDisenrollDate BETWEEN '1-1-2015' AND '1/31/2015'
AND me.ReinstatementDate IS NULL OR me.ReinstatementDate BETWEEN '1/1/2015' AND '1/31/2015'
AND SubscriberID LIKE '%H%')
 OR   ( me.StateDisenrollDate BETWEEN '2-1-2015' AND '2/28/2015'
AND me.ReinstatementDate IS NULL OR me.ReinstatementDate BETWEEN '2/1/2015' AND '2/28/2015'
AND SubscriberID LIKE '%H%')
 OR   ( me.StateDisenrollDate BETWEEN '3-1-2015' AND '3/31/2015' 
AND me.ReinstatementDate IS NULL OR me.ReinstatementDate BETWEEN '3/1/2015' AND '3/31/2015'
AND SubscriberID LIKE '%H%')
 OR   ( me.StateDisenrollDate BETWEEN '4/1/2015' AND '4/30/2015'
AND me.ReinstatementDate IS NULL OR me.ReinstatementDate BETWEEN '4/1/2015' AND '4/30/2015'
AND SubscriberID LIKE '%H%')
 OR   ( me.StateDisenrollDate BETWEEN '5-1-2015' AND getdate()
AND me.ReinstatementDate IS NULL OR me.ReinstatementDate BETWEEN '5/1/2015' AND getdate()
AND SubscriberID LIKE '%H%')
```

But I bet that this is not the correct result, you're mixing `AND` and `OR` without brackets. Hint: the order of precedence is `AND` first and then `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are trying to separate into each month of the year, but you aren't doing any aggregations or calculations at all, just listing out a set of results.

You could just combine your where clauses into one (and change the where to check that the month and year parts of the two dates are the same)?

```
select left((datename(mm, me.StateDisenrollDate)),3) as ReportedMonth,
me.StateDisenrollDate,
me.ReinstatementDate,
me.MemberID,
dis.DRI_Name,
case
    when me.ReinstatementDate is null then 'Disenrolled'
    else 'Reinstated' end as Status
from tblMemEnrollment me
left join tlkpDisenrolReasInvestigated dis on dis.DisenrolReasInvestigID = me.DisenrolRsnInvstgtdID
where SubscriberID like '%H%'
AND ((DATEPART(month, me.StateDisenrollDate) = DATEPART(month, me.ReinstatementDate)
AND DATEPART(year, me.StateDisenrollDate) = DATEPART(year, me.ReinstatementDate))
OR me.ReinstatementDate is null)
```